# Automatically reconnect to more preferred WLAN network if it becomes available

Tags: wireless, networking, virtualbox, network-manager

Assume this situation:
3 WLAN networks (with WPA) to which my notebook connects automatically.

Those are:
network_work (fixnet WLAN accesspoint)
network_home (fixnet WLAN accesspoint)
network_mobile (android mobile phone hotspot)

Furthemore assume virtualbox and windows 8.1 installed on my notebook, with bridged network to the wlan0 interface.

Present situation:
First, I switch on my notebook at home (auto-connects to network_home).
Then i go onto the train to work in the morning, (no laptop restart, auto-connects to network_mobile)
Then I arrive at work (no laptop restart, network annoyingly stays network_mobile)

Then I sometimes switch on VirtualBox with Windows 8.1 on it.
Windows 8.1 will usually download updates (up to 1 GB).

Now when I have the problem that if I forget to switch the WLAN network to network_work, Windows will use-up all my monthly data contengency completely (1 GB), until android blocks the connection. Unforunately, this has now happend for the second time, so it's unlikely I will not forget it in the future.

I also have the same problem on return from work.

How can I have Ubuntu automagically switch from network_mobile to network_home or network_work if it becomes available ?

And If that's not possible, how can I write a script that changes my WLAN network to wlan_work (so that I can run editions of that script at 08:30 o'clock and 19 o'clock) ?

Comment: Probably this bug/widhlist is relevant. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/366780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "priority"option for Network Manager is on the wishlist since long time; I think that the developers are not convinced about adding a knob for it. You can check the status on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/366780) and [upstream](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580018).

Anyway, you can manage the connection with script with:

```
nmcli nm wifi on
```

(or off) and

```
nmcli c up id "Auto MYwireless"
```

(you need the exact id, you can list them with `nmcli c list`)

More info in `man nmcli`.